# Creating Video in HTML5/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, google-nativeclient

Is it possible to create a video in Chrome either by HTML5/Javascript or using NaCl+OpenCV? I'm mostly concerned about codecs with the NaCl+OpenCV route. I'm looking for VP8 or MPEG4 output.

Basically I have a collection of JPEGS that I want to stitch together into a video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

naclports already has a port of ffmpeg ready to be used, it's therefore possible to compile any application that relies on ffmpeg into NaCl or PNaCl.

I'm not sure if you have a specific application in mind or not, but you may want to look at previous discussion of ffmpeg on the mailing list:
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/native-client-discuss/ffmpeg

Please let me know what you end up going with.

Comment: This isn't *quite* a link-only answer, so I'm not going to flag it. "It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide a link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."